# What happens when making a dying, surgeless character use her second wind?

Tags: dnd-4e, healing, conditions

Last session happened that our Barbarian fell unconscious, with 0 healing surges, and before she could spend her second wind.
The Avenger then made a Heal check to force her spending her second wind.

We decided that she wakes up with 1 hp by an interpretation of these rules:

> [Heal](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/skill.aspx?id=9)<sup>DDI</sup> (Wisdom)
>   [...]
>   **First Aid**
>   Make a Heal check to administer first aid.
>   First Aid: Standard action.
>   * DC: Varies depending on the task you’re attempting.
>   * Use Second Wind: Make a DC 10 Heal check to allow an adjacent character to use his or her second wind without the character having to take an action to do so. The character doesn’t gain the defense bonuses normally granted by second wind.
>   [...]

and

> [Healing and Dying](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=428)<sup>DDI</sup>
>   **Regain Hit Points:** When you are dying and receive healing, you go to 0 hit points and then regain hit points from the healing effect. If the healing effect requires you to spend a healing surge but you have none left, you are restored to 1 hit point.
>   **Become Conscious:** As soon as you have a current hit point total that’s higher than 0, you become conscious and are no longer dying. (You are still prone until you take an action to stand up.)

Is the *Use Second Wind* use of the Heal skill a healing effect eligible for the "regain hit points" part of the "Healing and Dying" rule?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the barbarian has no healing surges, she cannot use Second Wind. It requires her to **spend** one, which she does not have. And since the "Regain Hit Points" clause of Healing and Dying specifies that *you have none left*, this rule would never apply.

**Second Wind**<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=334)</sup> states:

> You can dig into your resolve and endurance to find an extra burst of vitality. In game terms, you spend a healing surge to regain some of your lost hit points, and you focus on defending yourself. Unless otherwise noted in the statistics block of a monster or a nonplayer character, this action is available only to player characters.
>
> [...]

Answer (score 16):

**She regains 1 hit point.**

Under [Healing the Dying](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=428)

> Regain Hit Points: When you are dying and receive healing, you go to 0 hit points and then regain hit points from the healing effect. If the healing effect requires you to spend a healing surge but you have none left, you are restored to 1 hit point.

Second wind grants the character the right to use a healing surge. With none remaining, her surge value is effectively 1 due to "Regain Hitpoints while dying." With that said, it could be stated that this is effectively a stabilization roll which would restore her to 0 HP, but that is not strictly suggested by the rules.

Comment: Uhm... that seems the reverse implication. Receiving healing => HS spent. But does HS spent => receiving healing?

Comment: Second wind is a pesudo-action, in the sense that it doesn't have a power card. However, all "spend HS" power cards have the healing keyword. Healing is defined as: "Healing
Powers that restore hit points." So, as Second Wind is a pseudo-power (without the fancy red border) that allows a character to restore hitpoints by spending a healing surge, it is de facto a healing power. Therefore, the regain hitpoints can *effectively* be read as "The your healing surge healed value becomes 1 when you are reduced to 0 healing surges remaining." From a practical matter, I've seen this used in play.

Comment: Also of note here is that the power card for Second wind that is printed by the character builder is devoid of the keyword healing. However you are explicitly using a heal skill in this instance. I am still quite confused on the correct interpretation here, but I think that ruled either way you are within the RAW.

Comment: By this interpretation, a paladin can use _Lay on Hands_ even if he has no healing surges to spend.

Comment: @Monkios - That is incorrect as Lay on Hands specifically stipulates that the giver MUST have a healing surge. "You must have at least one healing surge to use this power"