# Character Unconscious (negative HP) out of combat without a Leader

Tags: dnd-4e, healing

The question [Can an unconscious character use a healing surge?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3717/can-an-unconscious-character-use-a-healing-surge) discusses ways to get an Unconscious PC back on her feet.

I'm considering a situation where a PC was knocked out, combat has ended, the Unconscious PC is stablized and has healing surges remaining, there's no Leader (or it's the leader who's dropped) and nobody has a potion.

If the PC hasn't spent her second wind yet this fight, a (relatively easy) DC10 Heal check will allow the PC to spend her second wind and pop up.

But if the PC did spend her second wind, won't she get it back after a short rest? So in 5 minutes or so, another PC ought to be able to perform the DC10 Heal check, trigger the second wind, and bring her back to consciousness.

Then the only reason for the following quote from PHB p. 295 is when someone's out of surges or is alone, right?

> If someone has stabilized you using the Heal skill but you receive no healing, you regain hit points after an extended rest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Correct.**

Second Wind is an Encounter *power-like* option all characters have by default. That is: if it is spent during an encounter, it is available again after a short rest is taken.

Problems arise when the unconscious character is out-of-surges, but that's not the case of your question (more a matter of [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6854/what-happens-when-making-a-dying-surgeless-character-use-her-second-wind) ;)).